# CSS table equally-spaced columns

Tags: css, css-tables

I'd like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FJ6wX/) to have equally-spaced columns. In an older version, it worked, but I couldn't yet figure out what's the difference. If I copy the older HTML in a jsfiddle and apply the same CSS, it doesn't work either, so there's something missing I assume.

Comment: Have you inspected it with Firebug or Chrome Console?

Comment: Sure, haven't found anything so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Html and Css code are fine (just include the width 100% in the table).

The problem is the size of the images, if the images are larger than the width that the cell must have the other cells shrink.

Check this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/FJ6wX/3/

Comment: Thanks, found it. The css rule that gave the images `max-width` didn't match.